# Post a file using HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data) gives an error (A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I want to send a file using http post to mvc web application. That file contains html tags. Below is the code I have tried.

```
public void PostMultipleFiles(string url, string[] files)
{
    string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    httpWebRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    byte[] boundarybytes =System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary     +"\r\n");
    string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition:  form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";
    string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";
    memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "file" + i, files[i]);
        //string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "uplTheFile", files[i]);
        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(files[i], FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
    Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
    memStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
    memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
    memStream.Close();
    requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
    try
    {
        WebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string var = reader.ReadToEnd();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.InnerHtml = ex.Message;
    }
    httpWebRequest = null;
}
```

But when the request received to mvc application, exception occured. Exception - "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client". What is the reason for this exception and how can I post this file?

Comment: Can you post the contents of one of these files? The default behavior of some versions asp.net is to filter out requests with, eg. <> to help protect against script injection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Below is sample file content " <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve">
 <annots>
  <ink style="solid" width="1" color="#FF0000" opacity="1" creationdate="D:20150713061617Z00'00'" flags="print" date="D:20150713061617Z00'00'" page="0" rect="29.924474,221.353360,466.747338,618.014246">
   <popup date="D:20150713061626Z00'00'" page="0" rect="516.747338,668.014246,666.747338,818.014246">
   </popup>
   <inklist>"

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate the action with the AllowHtml attribute:

```
[AllowHtml]
public void PostMultipleFiles(string url, string[] files)
```

Note that this could be a potential security risk! See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I cant use this attribute because of the security risk. Is anything possible to do when i creating the request?

Comment: Looks like you are sending XML files. You could use this attribute and then to get rid of the security risk, only accept and save the upload if you can [validate the XML document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307379).